# Morse theory for isotopies of codimension 1 submanifolds and generalized bigon moves

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

I seem to have managed to convince myself of the validity of a certain result. If it does indeed hold (modulo non-catastrophic adjustments) I could really use a reference. Otherwise, I would also be really thankful if someone could point out the flaw in the strategy sketched below. My background in differential topology is really meager: please forgive me if the question is too basic or I make some silly gaffe.

We work in $C^{\infty}$. Let $n>1$, $H:N\times I\to M$, $I=[0,1]$ an isotopy of a compact $(n-1)$-manifold $N$ into an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ and $K$ some fixed  closed codimension $1$ submanifold of $M$. I would like to understand whether it is possible to find $H':N\times I\to M$ arbitrarily close to $H$ in the Whitney topology such that there are finitely many time points $0<t_{0}<t_{1}\dots t_{k}<1$ such that:

- For each $0\leq l\leq k-1$ and all $t,s\in (t_{k-1},t_{k})$ the hypersurfaces $H(N,t)=:N_{t}$ and $K$ are transverse and the configurations of $(N_{t},K)$ and $(N_{s},K)$ are the same in the sense that there is a homeomorphism between the pairs of spaces $(N_{s}\cup K,K)$ and $(N_{t}\cup K,K)$ (I actually need something much stronger, but that is a different can of worms which is better not to open here).
- The transition between the configuration associated to the interval $(t_{l},t_{l+1})$ and the one associated to the interval $(t_{l+1},t_{l+2})$ can be understood in terms of some "compression move" (for lack of a better name) as described (very informally) below. We are given a pair of hypersurfaces $K_{1},K_{2}\subseteq M$ in general position (in our context $K_{1}=N_{t}$ and $K_{2}=K$) as well as some $n$-dimensional smooth ball $B\subseteq M$, $B\cong I^{n}$ and $0<k\leq n$ satisfying the following conditions.

  - $\mathring{B}\cap(K_{1}\cup K_{2})=\emptyset$.
  - There is a decomposition of of $S^{k-1}\cong\partial I^{k}$ in two opposite hemispheres $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ so that $\partial B\cap K_{i}=E_{i}\times I^{n-k}$ for $i=1,2$.

  The move in question is the result of isotoping $E_{1}\times I^{n-k}$ onto $E_{2}\times I^{n-k}$ across $B$ and then pushing the image of $E_{1}\times I^{n-k}$ a bit further into the (local) side of $K_{2}$ opposite to where $E_{1}\times I^{n-k}$ originally was (where the push behaves as expected in a neighbourhood of $E_1\times I^{n-k}$). This can be seen as a generalization of a bigon removal or its inverse performed on a pair of curves on a surface.
  [image]
  This would seem to boil down to some kind of Morse-like result: namely, that up to arbitrarily small perturbation one can assume there are only finitely many points $\{(p_{k},s_{k})\}_{k=1}^{m}$ in $N\times I\cap H^{-1}(K)$ on which $dH(TN)\subseteq TK$ and that moreover $s_{i}\notin\{0,1\}$, the $s_{i}$ are all distinct and the following holds. For each $1\leq k\leq m$ there are local systems of coordinates $(x_{i})_{i=1}^{n-1}$ around $p_{k}$ ($x_{i}(p_{k})=0$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$) and $(y_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ at $q_{k}:=H(p_{k},s_{k})$ ($y_{i}(q_{k})=0$ for $1\leq i\leq n$) so that:
- $K$ is given by the equation $y_{n}=0$ locally around $q_{k}$
- there are $(\epsilon_{i})_{i=1}^{n-1}\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}$ such that locally around $(p_{k},s_{k})$ the map $H$ can be written with respect to the coordinates above as:
  $$(\underline{x},s)\to(\underline{x},(s-s_{k})+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\epsilon_{i}x_{i}^{2})$$
  Can't the latter be obtained by a similar application of Thom's transversality theorem to the one in the proof the classical result on existence of Morse functions? We consider the space $J^{1}(N\times I,M)$ of first order jets from $N\times I$ to $M$ and within it the submanifold $W$ consisting of all triples $((p,t),q,\lambda)$ where $((p,t),q)\in (N\times I)\times K$ and $\lambda\in Hom(T_{(p,t)}(N\times T),T_{q}M)$ has the property that $\lambda(T_{(p,t)}(N\times\{t\}))\subseteq T_{q}K\subseteq T_{q}M$. Then any $H'$ for which $j^{1}H'$ is transverse to $W$ should have all the desired properties other the ones involving the distribution of the $s_{k}$. Thom's transversality theorem then guarantees the existence of such $H'$ arbitrarily close to any given $H$. Some additional arguments are needed, including a version of Morse Lemma allowing first order terms, but I feel that should not be a problem (or is it?).

Does any of this check out? What would be a relevant reference?

EDIT: In retrospect, a similar result would seem to hold as long as at least one of the two submanifolds has codimension 1.

Comment: If you are in the codimension one situation, and your submanifold has an orientable normal bundle, you could think of it as the pre-image of a regular value, for some smooth Morse function  $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$. Your isotopy would give you a 1-parameter family of such Morse functions on $M$ (isotopy extension) and that would restrict to a 1-parameter family of real-valued functions on your other submanifold.  Here you could apply Cerf theory, which would say the function is generically Morse but has some birth-death points, which you could try to interpret as your generalized bigon moves.